# Disable System Printer Selection Popup window Ubuntu 20.04 Default Desktop Environment

Tags: printing

There is an Ubuntu 20.04 fresh installed machine we have in a Warehouse where a web based application is running (in Chrome), which is used by the people working there.
Workers are registering goods coming in and out, and printing Qr-codes and other tickets out of the application.
The client previously used a windows machine for this purpose where we could disable all popups, so the workers do not need to do an "extra click", just click the print button in the application.
However in Ubuntu I could not find a way to do this so far. The printer is set up and working, the only printer this machine can see is this one, on the popup it is the only one appearing.
Do anyone knows a way to skip this System Printer Selection popup?
Please see this image:

[image]

Comment: What type of file is being displayed? What is the viewer? Does a worker have to load a file herself or is it done automatically for her?

Comment: Since your app is a web-app running in Chrome, I wonder if this needs to be solved at the web-app level and not at the OS level. A similar question is [already answered in Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9213660/html-javascript-one-click-print-no-dialogs).

Comment: It is not a file, but the application is generating the content for printing. Basically a section in the app, in a single <div>. In Chrome, and in the app it is handled to not to show any print preview, or printer selection. But the Ubuntu system is showing it still. (as you can see in the picture)